# Using a condition related to a part of word in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
1                      2 
aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 picanha
aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 picanha
alcatra_Mat_15         picanha
alcatra_Mat_20         picanha
alcatra_Mat_25         picanha
picanha_Mat_20         picanha
picanha_Mat_25         picanha
```

and I would like to do this:

```
1                      2 
aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
alcatra_Mat_15         alcatra
alcatra_Mat_20         alcatra
alcatra_Mat_25         alcatra
picanha_Mat_20         picanha
picanha_Mat_25         picanha
```

If I have `alcatra` as a part of the word on `column 1` I will just want `alcatra` on `column 2`.

I know I can use this:

```
file$2[ file$1 == 'aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15'] <- 'alcatra'
```

but I have several situations almost 300. And I tried something like this:

```
file$2[ file$1 == '.*alcatra*'] <- 'alcatra'
```

But did'nt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr` and `stringr::str_detect`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = if_else(str_detect(V1, "alcatra"), "alcatra", V2))

#>                       V1      V2
#> 1 aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
#> 2 aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
#> 3         alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
#> 4         alcatra_Mat_20 alcatra
#> 5         alcatra_Mat_25 alcatra
#> 6         picanha_Mat_20 picanha
#> 7         picanha_Mat_25 picanha
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(v2 = case_when(grepl("alcatra", v1) ~ "alcatra",
                        grepl("picanha", v1) ~ "picanha"))
```

Output:

```
                      v1      v2
1 aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
2 aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
3         alcatra_Mat_15 alcatra
4         alcatra_Mat_20 alcatra
5         alcatra_Mat_25 alcatra
6         picanha_Mat_20 picanha
7         picanha_Mat_25 picanha
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15", "aquiles_alcatra_Mat_15", "alcatra_Mat_15", "alcatra_Mat_20", "alcatra_Mat_25", "picanha_Mat_20", "picanha_Mat_25"),
                 v2 = c("picanha", "picanha", "picanha", "picanha", "picanha", "picanha", "picanha"))
```